# Duplicate entries in Add/RemovePrograms control panel when using MsiSetExternalUI

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I created a setup for my product targeting Windows XP and later, to be installed using windows installer (WI). The resulting .msi file has a product code, let's say PC1 (actually a guid), and an upgrade code UC1 (also a guid). After some time, I created a new setup for a newer version of my product. The new .msi file has a new product code PC2 and the same upgrade code UC1 (also called a major upgrade). My company wants to install the .msi file with our own installer. For that, we basically use MsiInstallProduct to install the .msi file, while the entire UI is in our own install program (and we use MsiSetExternalUI to ask WI to send us notifications). The problem that I am having is the following:

- if the two builds of the product are installed on the same machine using "msiexec /i myapp.msi" then there will only be one entry in the "Add/Remove Programs" of "Programs and Features" control panel applet. or in other words, during the installation of the new build, the old one is uninstalled.
- if the two builds are installed on the same machine programatically using MsiInstallProduct, there will be two different entries in control panel.

Once again, only if I try to install it programatically (using either MsiOpenPackage+MsiDoAction or MsiInstallProduct), the upgrade does not happen and I end up with two entries in the control panel. I also found that if I do not set an external UI callback using MsiSetExternalUI, before calling MsiInstallProduct or MsiDoAction, then the upgrading part of a new installation also works as expected, no duplicate entries in the CP.

The callback that I use for MsiSetExternalUI is basically the same as the one in this MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368786(v=vs.85).aspx

What can I do (or what I need to handle in my callback) to avoid having duplicate/multiple entries in control panel?

Thanks and best regards, 
Levente

Comment: If you log the installer in the failed scenario, what does FindRelatedProducts report?  Also what is your ALLUSERS propety set to?  ( For example, a Per User install can't major upgrade a Per Machine install. )

Comment: I am running as an admin user. The product is installed for all. ALLUSERS=2 but I do not set this manually. The notifications INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART and INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO I only handle by returning IDOK.

Comment: I get this in the log: .... INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO: Action start 3:40:02: FindRelatedProducts.<br> INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA: Found application: {85144A07-AECF-4842-A9C4-9EBAFED473B7}

Comment: And a bit later, this:
....
INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO: Action start 3:40:02: RemoveExistingProducts.
INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA: Application: {85144A07-AECF-4842-A9C4-9EBAFED473B7}, Command line: UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE={7B3801F3-5831-4EA4-B176-0E9C12C844DB}  CLIENTUILEVEL= REMOVE=ALL

Comment: I am worried about the fact that the command line is wrong. As CLIENTUILEVEL has no value, I suspect that its vlue is being set to "REMOVE=ALL".

Comment: What does the log file look like in the situation that works?

Comment: Command Line: UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE={3144C2C0-E579-4A67-8094-86D8792BBF87} CLIENTUILEVEL=3 REMOVE=ALL

Answer (score 0):

Re our comments above, I did a google search for CLIENTUILEVEL and the first several hits indicate to me that CLIENTUILEVEL having a null value is normal and that REMOVE=ALL is working.   The comments indicate to go a little furthor down the log and find out why the uninstall (Remove existing products) is failing.  If you could email me a complete log file ( chrpai@iswix.com )  I could look through it for you.

[RemoveExistingProduct standard action](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winformssetup/thread/87c251d7-7ec9-4794-92dc-fdea6c8ca734)

[Link to article describing how to interpret Windows Installer log files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/04/04/link-to-article-describing-how-to-interpret-windows-installer-log-files.aspx) (see comments)

[RemoveExistingProducts running but not uninstalling Options](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.platformsdk.msi/browse_thread/thread/40410c383f957e8f?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same behavior with my ManagedMsiExec sample project: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2012/01/09/make-things-as-simple-as-possible-but-not-simpler-managedmsiexec-sample-app-shows-how-to-use-the-windows-installer-api-from-managed-code.aspx

Changing the logging behavior of my app didn't help in my case. But after (independently) noticing the same "CLIENTUILEVEL= REMOVE=ALL" strangeness in the logs, I found a workaround which was to explicitly call [MsiSetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set CLIENTUILEVEL to 0 before calling MsiDoAction.

This appears to me to be a bug with Windows Installer itself (incorrectly setting CLIENTUILEVEL during RemoveExistingProducts), but perhaps there's something else going on I don't understand. At any rate, I've had success with this change and maybe others can, too. :)